# How to Show and Hide My Image and Video Section Without ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

I am working online courses project. I have multiple courses fetch from data with the unique id. And My courses Id have images or video. When I clicked on my courses Id then it redirects to this page(blow code) in this page I have two section one is for images and second is for video but I want to image section hide when my video course Id run and similarly another hide. Please help me.
Thanks in Advance!!!

```
//pptLesson.html
    <!-- Images Section -->
    <section ng-show="isImageIdClicked">
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row" ng-init="image()">
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="img in images">
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <!-- <div class="numbertext">{{img.id}}</div> -->
                        <img class="size-i" src="{{img.oe_images}}" ng-show="isActive($index)" type="image" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a class="prev" ng-click="showPrev()" style="font-size:36px;">❮</a>
                        <a class="next" ng-click="showNext()" style="font-size:36px;">❯</a>
                        <div class="row paddi">
                            <div class="column" ng-repeat="img in images">
                                <div>
                                    <img class="demo cursor border-demo" ng-src="{{img.oe_images}}" type="image" ng-show="isActive($index)"
                                         style="width:100%; display: block !important;" data="{{img.id}}"
                                        ng-click="currentSlide(img.id)" alt="{{img.oe_images}}" type="image">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>    

    <!-- Video Section -->
    <section ng-show="isVideoIdClicked">
        <div class="container" id="myCarousel" >
            <div class="row" ng-init="image()">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="mySlides" ng-repeat="img in images">
                        <!-- <div class="numbertext">{{img.id}}</div> -->
                        <div>
                            <video width="100%" id="video" controls="controls" ng-show="isActive($index)">
                                <source ng-src="./assets/vdo/{{img.oe_images}}" type="video" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a ng-click="showPrev()" class="carousel left" href="#myCarousel" style="font-size:36px;float:left;padding: 50px 0px;">❮</a>
                        <a ng-click="showNext()" class="carousel right" href="#myCarousel" style="font-size:36px;float:right;padding: 50px 0px;">❯</a>
                        <div class="row paddi">
                            <div class="column" ng-repeat="img in images">
                                <div>
                                    <video controls="controls" ng-src="./assets/vdo/{{img.oe_images}}"
                                        type="video/mp4" ng-show="isActive($index)" style="width:100%"></video>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--./Video Section -->
Controller

    /*-----Redirect to perticular course start by id---------*/
         $scope.getCourse  =function(id){
            window.localStorage.setItem('id',id);
            $window.location ="pptLesson.html";
        };
         /*-----./Redirect to perticular course start by id---------*/

         /*-----PPT Images/Videos---------*/
         $scope.image = function(){
            var id=window.localStorage.getItem('id');
            $http.get(baseURL+'pptImagesById/'+id).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

            function successCallback(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.images=response.data;
                window.localStorage.setItem('img_l',$scope.images.length);
                console.log($scope.images.length);
            }
            function errorCallback(error){
                console.log(error);
            }   
         };
         /*-----./PPT Images/videos---------*/
```

Comment: clarify more and tell what you have tried so far

Comment: I have video and images courses list dynamically and some courses included PPT images and some courses included videos. and in one page i have defined my code for videos and images as shown in above. now i want to when I click on video id  course then i want to display only video and hide other images...

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: please see my edited question. I have tried ng-if condition this is not working and also I am trying ng-show condition then it displays only images but when I click on video Id then it not display videos.

Comment: what is isActive function doing?

Comment: isActive function is for image Slider

Comment: make a function and call it on the click of video/image tab and inside this function simply change means set/unset a variable. let variable be isShowVideo and check the condition for this variable. when set show videos and when not show image

Comment: where do you click to open image or video

Comment: Thanks but I have made a function already

Comment: Sir, please check to blow answer. my videos is not displayed otherwise everything working properly

Comment: that's the thing i am saying you have to change the value of variable on function call you have fixed the values

Comment: I have asked where you click to open the images or videos on div or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to declare one variable of type boolean which will check whether image id was clicked or video id. 
   Eg. `$scope.isImageIdClicked = true;`
2. You need to alter variable value when you click on image id or video id. If image id is clicked then set that variable(`isImageIdClicked`) to **true** and if video id is clicked then set that variable to **false**.
3. Assign `isImageIdClicked` variable to `ng-show="isImageIdClicked"` condition in `img` tag and `ng-show="!isImageIdClicked"` to `div` where your `video` tag is present.

Comment: but, When I click on video Id then it not display because our videos already ng-show="!isImageIdClicked" then how it will show??

Comment: You should call function on click of image/video id to toggle your variable value as I had mentioned in my answer (Refer 2nd point)

Comment: Sir, I'm beginner can you give me an example of how I will call a function.

Comment: Write one function in your controller which will change value of "isImageIdClicked". Whenever you are clicking on image id, call that function using ng-click="your_function()"  

OR

Whenever you are clicking on image id, write ng-click="isImageIdClicked=true;"  and Whenever you are clicking on video id, write ng-click="isImageIdClicked=false;"  (Note: This is not a good practice. Variable toggling should be done in controller)

Comment: @MohammadFareed Did you try?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have already given the ng-click function dynamically for courses id. I want to without the ng-click show and hide my section. please show my edited question

Comment: Where is your click function which will change isImageIdClicked variable. Also, change ng-show="isVideoIdClicked" to ng-show="!isImageIdClicked" in Videos section and try.

Comment: this is my click function [ <a ng-click="getCourse(course.oe_id)" class="btn btn btn-sm btn-green btn-round">Start</a> ]. from here I am got images and videos data from server

Comment: and this function redirects to here.. this is controller code   $scope.getCourse  =function(id){
        window.localStorage.setItem('id',id);
        $window.location ="pptLesson.html";
    };

Comment: can you update your question by writing your controller logic?

Comment: Please use angular ui router for state management insted of changing url by window.location. It will be better if you can code in  stackblitz and share link  here so that we can resolve it quickly